# How to pass field value in powershell script

Tags: powershell, command

In PowerShell how to pass field value, field names are Environment, Salesforce Username and Salesforce Password but here i am able to pass username and password with `Salesforce.ps1 -salesforce_username xyz -salesforce_password abc` but not able to pass environment field.
I have tried this code `Salesforce.ps1 -environment dev -salesforce_username xyz -salesforce_password abc` but getting the below error:

> parameter can not be found that matches parameter name -environment,
> NamedparameterNotFoundException.

Comment: What is the parameter you're trying to pass? Is the parameter even there? Can we look at the code you've tried?

Comment: I have tried this code "Salesforce.ps1 -environment dev -salesforce_username xyz -salesforce_password abc" but getting parameter can not be found that matches parameter name -environment, NamedparameterNotFoundException.

Comment: So, your `SalesForce` script either does not have a parameter called `environment`, or it is called differently there (typo perhaps ?)

Comment: I agree with @Theo, could be a type in the parameter unless  its just not there. You should be able to open the ps1 and see whats there.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check here:

- Please check your `Salesforce.ps1` script to make sure that the environment parameter exists and you're spelling it correcrtly while calling the parameter.
- If you're using `ParameterSetName` attribute with your parameter, make sure the value you're providing in there is exactly the same as your parameter name.

In case the above points does not fix your problem, the community can provide you more assistance if you can share the snippet of your `Salesforce.ps1` script where you're declaring your parameters.